# What is the proper way to do this in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-tokio

Suppose a loop on main like this:

```rs
use crate::modules::very_ext::{one, two};
use crate::modules::much_wow::logic;

let result;
loop {
  let foo = one.next().await.expect("boom");

  // Do something with foo
  result = logic(foo)
}
```

This far, great. What happens when the logic inside the loop needs to "react" to multiple external events?

If we do something like this:

```rs
use crate::modules::very_ext::{one, two};
use crate::modules::much_wow::logic;

let result;
loop {
  let foo = one.next().await.expect("boom");
  let bar = two.next().await.expect("boom");

  // Do something with foo
  result = logic(foo, bar)
}
```

then `logic` will only run after:

- `foo` resolves first
- then `bar` eventually resolves as well

(which is not what we want, we need to react whenever a new value for
either `foo` or `bar` is externally ready to be passed to the main
loop).

By reading `tokio`'s docs, my guess is that this can be solved by using threads and channels. But I'm confused on exactly how. I am thinking it like this:

- Create an `mpsc` channel.
- Spawn `one` and `two` into their own threads.
- Each thread pushes a value on the channel with perhaps some encapsulation that distinguishes it.
- The main loop is the single consumer that "reacts" as the values come in over the `mpsc` channel.

Am I overthinking this? Is there a simpler way (assume the general problem with multiple producers, not just two)?

Thank you!

Comment: Use [select](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.6.1/tokio/macro.select.html) to wait on multiple futures concurrently

Comment: @harmic The docs say "cancelling the remaining branches.". Will this not be a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can spawn lightweight tasks out of both futures, which will allow you to await them both without serializing them. It is conceptually similar to the solution you proposed, but doesn't use additional threads (it runs `foo` and `bar` on the normal executor threads, interleaving them with other futures as they await), and the channels created are one-shot channels highly optimized for this purpose.

```
loop {
    // spawn foo and bar to run in the background
    let foo = tokio::spawn(one.next());
    let bar = tokio::spawn(two.next());
    // awaiting foo now also executes bar
    let foo = foo.await.unwrap().expect("boom");
    let bar = bar.await.unwrap().expect("boom");

    result = logic(foo, bar);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`futures::future::try_select`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/future/fn.try_select.html) for this if you have exactly two futures to wait on, or [`futures::future::select_all`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.15/futures/future/fn.select_all.html) if you have more than two - they return any remaining unresolved Futures so you can still wait on them in the future if you want.

Note that `select_all` requires that all futures resolve to the same type, so you may need to introduce a wrapper `enum` with one variant per type of your futures if they are different. Then you would `map` each of the Futures you're awaiting into their relevant enum wrapper before calling `select_all`.